# Unable to download generated PDF when controller action is called from Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I am returning FilestreamResult from controller
I tried both way jquery and ajax but cant succeed for download pdf/xlsx file from controller.

Controller:

```
    var filestream = new FileStream(pdfoutputpath + ".pdf", FileMode.Open);
                return new FileStreamResult(filestream, "application/pdf");
```

View code using jquery:

```
function downloadpdffile(id) {
                $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
                var url = "/WorkInstructions/WorkinstructionDownload";
                $.get(url, { id: id, fileformat: 2 }, function () {

                });
            }
```

using ajax:

```
 function downloadpdffile(id) {
                $(".popup-overlay, .popup-content").removeClass("active");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/WorkInstructions/WorkinstructionDownload",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { id: id, fileformat: 2 },
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {

                    }

                });
```

Comment: What happens if you change your ajax to `POST`? Also, how is your controller method decorated? `HttpGet, HttpPost`, etc. Does your controller method get hit when the call is made? Add the error callback to your ajax request and place something in the body of the success and error callback functions and see which one is hit, if the error is hit, you can get some information from the XHR object.

Comment: can you show your complete controller code?

Comment: is it necessary to use ajax or you just want to download that pdf. or xls file?

Comment: If you need to receive a file via `ajax` I would refer to this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `success` function of your ajax call:

```
success: function(){
    window.location = '@Url.Action("WorkinstructionDownload", "WorkInstructions", new { id = id, fileformat = 2})';
}
```

although I don't think ajax is providing any value here unless I'm missing something. You could easily take the contents of that `success` function I posted above and put it outside of the ajax call altogether (and delete the ajax call). Or you could just simply do the following and remove the script altogether:

`<a href="@Url.Action("WorkinstructionDownload", "WorkInstructions", new { id = id, fileformat = 2 })">Download Form</a>`

Comment: well, apriciate your work but I tried it's not working.

Comment: I've put together use cases for both options I listed which do not use ajax and they are working. Can you provide more information as to what's going wrong? Are you receiving an error? I suspect you have an issue with your controller action if this isn't working. In that case, you'll need to post your entire controller action to your question

Comment: Now I found another solution and it's working,I customly creating ancor tag <a> and calling from js and working as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.open function to achieve your task if there is no problem in your controller. I used same technique in my project.

```
var downloadURL='@Url.Action("WorkinstructionDownload", "WorkInstructions", new { id = id, fileformat = 2})'
window.open(downloadURL)
```